# blocking/unblocking websites in C# according to ip

Tags: c#, parental-control

I need help about blocking and unblocking websites in my C# parental control software project. I tried it by using the host file but host file only blocks the domain name not the ip. Even the website address is written on the host file, i can reach that website by entering the ip. How can i block both the domain name and ip in C# ? Is there a way to do it by using host file?

Comment: You'd need to directly intercept all IP-level traffic in whatever scope you're targeting (i.e. system-wide, app-specific, etc.). IP interception is costly but far more effective than simply blocking hostnames (as DNS-based solutions do, i.e. OpenDNS).

Comment: You do understand that blocking websites by ip address is counter productive right?  I suggest skipping the custom software you don't understand how to write and simply use something like OpenDNS to provide your filtering needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem :( . I found a way to block websites using proxy. I'm using Titanium Web Proxy. It works great. But there are problems with HTTPS websites. I'm trying to fix this problem. But I think there are a way to fix it.

https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy/